# Как можно разделить строку на массив с сохранением пустых ячеек

Tags: javascript

Есть массив:

```
const dataSplit = 'Текст<tt><tt>Текст<tt>100'
```

Должно получится

```
["Текст", "","", "Текст","", "100"]
```

Попробовал через split, но он по другому принципу работает

Answer (score 0):

Скорее вопрос не про сохранение, а про замену `<tt>` пустой ячейкой.

```js
const reSplit = /(?=<tt>)|(?<=<tt>)/g
const reTT = /<tt>/

const str = 'Текст<tt><tt>Текст<tt>100'

console.log(
  str.split(reSplit).map((v)=>reTT.test(v) ? '' : v)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dataSplit = 'Текст<tt><tt>Текст<tt>100';
console.log(
  dataSplit.replace(/^<t|t>$/g, '').split(/<t|t>(?:<t)?/)
);
```

Если `<tt>` не может находиться в начале и/или конце входной строки, то подвыражение `.replace(/^<t|t>$/g, '')` можно убрать.